# Keeping image-quality when saving Word as PDF

Tags: svg, pdf, image-quality, microsoft-word

I would like to keep SVG images inserted in a Word (2016) document **without lowering their native quality** (*first image*) when saved as PDF. Default save-to-PDF from word messes up the images' quality (*middle image*), which makesthe image look crappy and unreadable. I searched for solutions and used Nitro PDF creator for printing the word document into PDF. This does save the image quality (*third image*), although changes dashed lines to solid ones. The problem with this approach is that Hyperlinks are not saved into the PDF, and I would love to keep them.

[image]

Does anyone know **how to save a Word document keeping hyperlinks and the image quality** (and possibly its dashed lines)?

Comment: I fear the problems you are encountering are inherent in Microsoft applications. MS apps simply are **not** designed for high-quality or print resolution output. This is why Microsoft files are *often* rejected by print production teams. Your best bet *may* be to change the SVG images into RGB PNG images. But ultimately without knowing the *entire* end goal, it's difficult to be definitive.

Comment: Transforming the SVG images into PNG did resolve the moving or changing images, but messed up the quality. What I chose to do is use PDFcreator with maximum dpi to retain image quality, and once the PDF is created insert hyperlinks into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of what software was used to create the SVG, but if possible try saving the file as a WMF. Word will insert this format natively, and graphics will retain their scalability when saving to PDF. I'm a technical writer and we use this format exclusively in our Word documents. If your document has a significant number of graphics, the file size does tend to be a bit higher though, so that may be something to keep in mind.

FWIW: I use CorelDRAW - there are a couple of quirks to keep in mind when saving as a WMF (that may or may not be relevant in other software):

- You need to make sure that strokes are not set to "scale with object" as that can occasionally cause some oddities upon import into Word.
- Sometimes the right side and bottom of graphics will get a bit "cut off" (either during the save to WMF or upon inserting into Word; I'm not sure which), so I will usually place a rectangle with no stroke/no fill, slightly larger than my graphic, behind my objects to account for this inadvertent cropping.